# How do we add Native app links in git markup

Tags: github, markup

How do i add native app links such as `MyApp://1234` in Git Markup

```
[link to 1234](MyApp://1234)
```

does not seem to work.

Assumption is the MyApp is already registered with the OS

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question, so we can help you.

Comment: @LewWinczynski updated, please let me know if it is still unclear